# how to use git commit template in tower

Tags: git, templates, commit, git-tower

Is there a way tower uses git commit template that is setup in git config? I tried to execute below command and it create a template when trying to commit from command prompt however doesn't work with tower. However git hooks works with both command prompt and tower.

```
git config commit.template <template_file_name>.txt
```

Comment: got to know from tower support that its not supported now

Comment: could you please show your working example using githooks?